# Robocopy mirroring only based on filename

Tags: robocopy

I would like to mirror a shared drive directory to a Sharepoint library.
It seems that Robocopy copy each time every file.
My command line is

```
Robocopy "source" "dest" /MIR /FFT /Z /XA:H /W:5
```

I will never have a different file in the source with the same name so how can I do a robocopy based only on the file name ?

Comment: Are you migrating to Sharepoint Online? If so, have you considered using the Sharepoint Migration Tool? - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool

Comment: It's not a migration. It's between a samba shared drive and a sharepoint library

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

`robocopy source destination /ns /E /SEC /COPYALL /unicode /np /PURGE /Z /R:0 /W:0 /UNILOG+:C:\Users\myuser\robocopy.log`

Comment: I will try. It it also a mirroring ? Because a need to delete the files from destination that are missing in source

Comment: Yes it does mirroring. Actually /MIR is the equivalent of /E /PURGE, which I have included. The difference is that if using /MIR and the destination directory exists, the destination directory security settings are overwritten.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Comment: `NOTE : Security may not be copied - Destination might not support persistent ACLs.

ERROR : You do not have the Manage Auditing user right.
*****  You need this to copy auditing information (/COPY:U or /COPYALL).`

Comment: Its the error I have received. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Don't you have admin rights? If you do have them, do you start an elevated command line? (right click, run as administrator on cmd).

Comment: If you don't have admin rights, remove /COPYALL from parameters and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding `/xo /xn` with`/MIR` would do it. That would exclude files with older or newer timestampe